# Crear conexión a Servidor Remoto para escritura y lectura

Tags: javascript, php, sql, html5, mysqli

Comunidad, deseo crear una conexión a un servidor, remoto para crear un login/registro y otras actividades desde un aplicativo web, soy nuevo en esto de la programación de HTML, JS, CSS, casi todo lo hago mediante powerquery de excel, por ahora solo tengo los diseños del menú y el de login pero ya quede trancado  no veo la forma de crear la conexión y probar, es decir como seria la sintaxis de los comandos, o mediante que aplicación la debo realizar, actualmente uso VSCode

````
    $conexion =mysqli_connect("192.xxx.x.xx", "hbase00", "base0","Indicadores_Base_0");

    if($conexion){
        echo 'conectado';
    }else{
        echo 'no conectado';
    }


?>```
````

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que reformules tu pregunta y te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es nada difícil. Esta es la forma habitual usando objetos.
Lo de localhost se refiere a la ubicación del servidor de la base de datos, que si es en el mismo servidor que la web con la que trabajes es localhost.
Si tienes el servdor MySQL en otro sitio tendrías que cambiarlo, y además tener permiso para acceder desde otro lugar.

```
$conexion= new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'base_de_datos');
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die('Error de Conexión (' . $conexion->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conexion->connect_error);
}
```

A partir de aquí ya puedes hacer operaciones con la tabla o tablas que necesites mediante las sentencias MySQL que precises

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
    $conexion->query($query);
```

Creo que esto te puede orientar un poco.

Comment: Buenos días, si funciona cuando la conexión es remota pero cuando me intento conectar a una IP especifica de otro servidor remoto, ya se valido el usuario y clave, pero genera error alli es donde radica mi duda en referencia a conexión remota

Comment: Re almete no se si sera tema de que el servido es por SQL o debo usar programas cosas como AJAX o algo similar ya que revisando las conexiones solo se realizan con la IP

Comment: No termino de entender. Con esta solución debieras conectar sin problema mediante un programa php a tu base de datos. Si lo haces mediante IP muy probablemente el servidor en esa IP no acepte conexiones remotas. No muestras el error que obtienes.

Comment: Gracias ya encontré el error y es las extensiones del PHP saludos